# PHP : Not able to call connection object

Tags: php, mysql

I am a newbie in PHP programming. I have created a config and a script which prints all my MySQL database information. Here is my config :

```
class DbManager{
protected $dbh;
public $dbhost = '127.0.0.1';
public $dbname = 'bookstore';
public $dbuser = 'root';
public $dbpass = '';

public function getConnection(){
    try{
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->dbhost;dbname=$this->dbname", $this->dbuser, 
    $this->dbpass);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    return $dbh;            
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        echo "Error : " . $e;
    }

}
```

}
and, this is my script to get my database information :

```
require_once('config.php');
class ShowData extends DbManager{
  public function getInfo(){
    $dbh= getConnection();
    $smt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM books");
    $smt->execute();
    $result = $smt->fetchAll();
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($result);
  }
}
```

I am getting the error : `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function getConnection()`.
I am not able to make a connection variable by which I can make my SQL queries. I have my suspicions about `$dbh= getConnection()`. Am I making the queries alright?

Comment: Any error messages, that  will lead you in the right direction?

Comment: @BenRoob check my edited question

Comment: is your `getConnection` method is in any class?

Comment: @B.Desai Yes, it is.

Comment: Ok, after your edit: you are missing $this->getConnection() (you call getConnection). You are in object scope!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `getConnection` is in class so you need to call like `$this->getConnection()`

```
class ShowData extends DbManager{
  public function getInfo(){
    $dbh= $this->getConnection(); // change this line
    $smt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM books");
    $smt->execute();
    $result = $smt->fetchAll();
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($result);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. My code works now. Thank you.